# Dynamically Render expanding with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have developed a JS function to dynamically render cards on the page, in accordance with the data fetched from the backend API.

Here is the code:-

```js
for (var i = 0; i < booking_data.length; i++) {
  var container = document.createElement("div");
  container.className = "container";

  var card = document.createElement("div");
  card.className = "card";

  //data tp append to the card
  var data = booking_data[i];

  var heading = document.createElement("h2");
  heading.textContent = "Booking ID: " + data["booking_id"] + "  (PAYMENT STATUS: " + data["booking_status"] + ")";

  var class_title = document.createElement("h2");
  class_title.textContent = data["title"];

  var parent_name = document.createElement("h4");
  parent_name.textContent = "Parent Name: " + data["user_name"];

  var start_date = document.createElement("h4");
  start_date.textContent = "Start Date: " + data["start_date"];

  var end_date = document.createElement("h4");
  end_date.textContent = "End Date: " + data["end_date"];

  card.appendChild(button);
  card.appendChild(heading);
  card.appendChild(class_title);
  card.appendChild(parent_name);
  card.appendChild(start_date);
  card.appendChild(end_date);



  container.appendChild(card);
  bookingEditForm.appendChild(container);

}
```

What I want to do to achieve that when a button is clicked on the card, it expands and shows the form.

Comment: What is bookingEditForm?

Comment: The snippet does not work as there is no `booking_data` - where is the HTML? Where is this button of which you speak?

Comment: The function generates the HTML, and i want to bind a button to each card. Which when clicked expands the said card.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want an expandable/collapsible element which should be your card.Why don't you explore the accordion element in HTML? I believe it will solve your problem.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp - You can go through this link to checkout a basic accordion implementation.

Comment: Thank You, though I just used the <details> and <summary> tags instead.